# Cannot read property 'func' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting the following 2 errors with my React Native project, using Expo in the Simulator.

Can anyone shed any light on what I should be looking to fix? I've seen a couple of people with similar 'undefined' issues but I was unable to a gain a solution from them. I'm not even sure which file I should be looking at! ExceptionsManager.js is a file inside 'node_modules/react-native' so does that mean anything? Any ideas?

Many thanks.

```
Cannot read property 'func' of undefined - ExceptionsManager.js:65 
handleException               @ ExceptionsManager.js:65
handleError                   @ InitializeCore.js:106
reportFatalError              @ error-guard.js:46
guardedLoadModule             @ require.js:133
_require                      @ require.js:118
(anonymous)                   @ config.json:1
executeApplicationScript      @ debuggerWorker.js:40
(anonymous)                   @ debuggerWorker.js:65

Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication) - ExceptionsManager.js:65 
handleException               @ ExceptionsManager.js:65
handleError                   @     InitializeCore.js:106
reportFatalError              @ error-guard.js:46
__guard                       @ MessageQueue.js:267
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue    @ MessageQueue.js:115
(anonymous)                   @ debuggerWorker.js:72
```

Comment: What are you trying to do when encountered this problem? Can you provide some code?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Sorry, I should have said that I'm simply trying to run a previously-built project (not by me) in the simulator for the first time so there's no specific code I'm working on in this instance. I guess this is going to be difficult to pinpoint then?

Comment: Could you please add a few more details: a project/code, project structure. [Here is a quick start guide for expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/index.html) for expo.